# How to encode/decode a reference to a selector?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have a class with an instance variable of type SEL, which is a reference to a selector. Inside encodeWithCoder/initWithCoder, how do I encode/decode this type of variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can covert it to/from a string with NSStringFromSelector and NSSelectorFromString. Selectors are actually strings under the hood anyway.

Comment: Tom's right that they're strings internally, but don't try to take advantage of that implementation detail. Use the functions he named if you want to use a selector as a string or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`encodeValueOfObjCType:at:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/encodeValueOfObjCType:at:):

```
SEL s = ...;
[coder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(SEL) at:&s];
```

You can also use [`NSValue`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsvalue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for key archiving.

Or simply you can use [`NSStringFromSelector`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector) and [`NSSelectorFromString`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString).

Comment: which one would be the best as far as performance? I need to encode quite a lot of these objects.

Comment: you need to do some profiling.  I think that you are better off using `NSStringFromSelector` because the API is easier to use and get right.